# Write the output of a script in a html page using flask

Tags: python, html, flask

I wrote a script that makes me able to run a script and then to get the output I want, I am trying to write the output in a html page, how can I do that? this is my script:

```
def execute(cmd):
    os.system(cmd)
    to_return =dict()
    for filename in files:
        with open(filename, 'r') as f:
            data = f.read()
            to_return[filename] = data
    return to_return

output = execute('./script')
print output
```

Any Idea of how I can generate an html page where I can print the result of running this script??

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In your views.py, under the corresponding route, do

```
@app.route('/route_name')
def script_output():
    output = execute('./script')
    return render_template('template_name.html',output=output)
```

And in your template,

```
<p>{{ output }}</p>
```

Comment: Thank you so much your answer really helped! I was stuck for days!! Just one last thing, how can I get the output in a list or so, I mean something nice to read, cause now I get the output displayed but it's all in such a mess!

Comment: @siva i get an error `Undefined variable 'execute'`. Can you tell me what i'm missing? #juststartedFlask

Comment: @ans2human, `execute` needs to be defined. Please check the question.