# writing Flask console logs to an HTML template as and when it appears

Tags: python, shell, flask, console

I have a Flask App that runs 2 shell scripts and renders an HTML template **index.html**.

```
import subprocess
from flask import Flask, request, render_template  
  
app = Flask(__name__)        

@app.route('/result', methods =["POST"]) 
def process_html_input(): 
    if request.method == "POST": 
        git_url = request.form.get("giturl") 
        subprocess.call(['sh', 'installer_script1.sh']) 
        subprocess.call(['sh', 'installer_script2.sh']) 
    return render_template("index.html") 
    
if __name__=='__main__': 
    app.run()
```

I want to print the content of the Python console as and when it appears (while the script is executing) to the same HTML template **index.html** -

```
<html lang="en">
  <body>
        
  </body>
</html>
```

I'm unable to write it, can someone help me with the python and HTML code ?
I have tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35840386/write-the-output-of-a-script-in-a-html-page-using-flask) but unable to make it work.

Answer (score 2):

Check the following code that runs one command, try it, and if it worked you can put other commands as well.

**Notes:**

- Yield is a generator function, it helps you to get the result of the subprocess.
- Using -u switch when you want to run the shell in order to prevent output buffering.

```py
import subprocess
from flask import Flask, request, render_template  
  
app = Flask(__name__)        

@app.route('/result', methods =["POST"]) 
def process_html_input(): 
    
    def inner():
        git_url = request.form.get("giturl") 
        command = ['sh', '-u installer_script1.sh'] # -u: avoid buffering the output 
        
        proc = subprocess.Popen(
            cmd,
            stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
        )
        
        for line in proc.stdout:
            yield highlight(line, BashLexer(), HtmlFormatter())
        
    env = Environment(loader=FileSystemLoader('app/templates'))
    tmpl = env.get_template('index.html')
    return Response(tmpl.generate(result=inner())) 
    
if __name__=='__main__': 
    app.run()
```

Also, you can check and use the proposed solution of the following link:

[HTTP streaming of command output in Python Flask](https://mortoray.com/2014/03/04/http-streaming-of-command-output-in-python-flask/)